# Using liquibase in java gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, amazon-redshift, liquibase

I added liquibase plugin and consumed liquibase-core,redshift-ext dependencies. I created liquibase.properties.

```
url="jdbc url" //redshift 
username=xxxxx
password=xxxxx
driver=com.amazon.redshift.jdbc.Driver
```

In my main class I calling the update method like this,

```
Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(
                new JdbcConnection(redShiftConnection));
        Liquibase liquibase = new liquibase.Liquibase("create_table.xml",
                new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database);
        liquibase.update(new Contexts());
```

this is giving me the following error:

`Error getting default schema liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL select current_schema(): [Amazon][JDBC](11340) Not all output parameters are registered.`

What else should I configure ?